# Register all modules exported using MEF and autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, mef

Using the Autofac.Mef extension I want to register exported Modules. Is there a way?

### Exporting

```
[Export(typeof(IModule))]
public class MyModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<SampleJob>().AsSelf();
    }
}
```

### Registering

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".");
builder.RegisterComposablePartCatalog(catalog); //This would register all exported types.
builder.RegisterModule(//All IModules registerd as that type I want to register as Modules)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a very good writeup about one such approach in [Unleashing modules – part 2](http://ondevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/04/unleashing-modules-part-2.html). The approach is to use a delegate as a factory to create the modules instead of exporting the `IModule` type.

```
using Autofac;

/// <summary>
/// Creates an <see cref="IModule" /> that's responsible for loading
/// dependencies in the specified context.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mode">The mode the application is running in, let's the implementor
/// of the factory load different dependenices for different modes.</param>
/// <returns>An <see cref="IModule" />.</returns>
public delegate IModule ModuleFactory(ApplicationMode mode);


/// <summary>
/// Describes different modes an application can run in.
/// </summary>
public enum ApplicationMode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The application is running in a test environment.
    /// </summary>
    Test = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// The application is running in a staging environment.
    /// </summary>
    Staging = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// The application is running in production environment.
    /// </summary>
    Production = 2
}
```

The real magic happens in the `ComposedModule`.

```
using Autofac.Builder;
using Autofac;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;


/// <summary>
/// An <see cref="Autofac.Builder.Module" /> is composed by with the help of
/// the System.ComponentModel.Composition (MEF) framework.
/// </summary>
public class ComposedModule
    : global::Autofac.Builder.Module
{
    #region Fields
    private ApplicationMode mode;
    private ComposablePartCatalog catalog;
    [Import(typeof(ModuleFactory))]
    private IEnumerable<ModuleFactory> RegisteredModuleFactories; 
    #endregion

    #region Construction
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new ComposedModule using the specified catalog to
    /// import ModuleFactory-instances.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mode">The mode the application is running in.</param>
    /// <param name="catalog">The catalog used to import ModuleFactory-instances.</param>
    public ComposedModule(ApplicationMode mode, ComposablePartCatalog catalog)
    {
        if (catalog == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("catalog");

        this.mode = mode;
        this.catalog = catalog;

        this.ImportFactories();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new ComposedModule that loads all the ModuleFactories
    /// exported in assemblies that exists in the directory specified in 
    /// the <param name="modulesDirectoryPath" />-parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mode">The mode the application is running in.</param>
    /// <param name="catalog">The catalog used to import ModuleFactory-instances.</param>
    public ComposedModule(ApplicationMode mode, string modulesDirectoryPath)
        : this(mode, new DirectoryCatalog(modulesDirectoryPath)) { } 
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    private void ImportFactories()
    {
        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        batch.AddPart(this);

        var container = new CompositionContainer(this.catalog);
        container.Compose(batch);
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        foreach (var factory in this.RegisteredModuleFactories)
        {
            var module = factory(this.mode);
            builder.RegisterModule(module);
        }
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

## Usage

```
public class MyModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        builder.RegisterType<SampleJob>().AsSelf();
    }

    [Export(typeof(ModuleFactory))]
    public static ModuleFactory Factory = x => new MyModule();
}
```

See the post for complete details.

Also, you might want to check out these links:

- http://buksbaum.us/2009/12/06/bootstrapping-an-application-with-mef-and-autofac/
- http://kalcik.net/2014/02/09/cooperation-between-the-autofac-and-the-microsoft-extensibility-framework/